# Proper error handling of nested functions

Tags: r, function, debugging, purrr

I have a function `superFoo()` which calls other functions `foo()`. Each `foo()` functions has different outputs, i.e., lists, data-frame, scalar.
I need to:

1. Stop the execution of `superFoo()` whenever any `foo()` fails (it signals an error or warning)
2. Capture the error message.

   ```
   foo = function(a){
       log(a)
   }

   superFoo = function (a){
       varA = foo(a)

       # IF foo(a) fails, superFoo has to: stop and     return NA

       varB = foo(varA+3)
       varA + varB
   }

   # Iteration
   HyperY = setups %>% split(.$IDsample) %>% 
       map(superFoo)
   ```

I know I can do `tryCatch()` inside `superFoo()`, capture the error message and return NA in `superFoo()`. Something like:

```
varA = tryCatch({foo()}, error=(return(NULL)), warning(return(NULL)))
if (is.null(varA)) { return(list(NA, errorMessage)}
```

The problem is that I have 9 functions `foo()` in `superFoo()`. I wonder if there is a more efficient way of programming this.

Another alternative is `purrr:safely()`. This is, however, as wordy as `tryCatch()` cause I have to redeclare `foo()` in `superFoo()` before calling it:

```
safeFoo = safely(foo)
varA = safeFoo(a)
if (is.null(varA)) { return(list(NA, errorMessage) }
```

What is a good practice of error handling in nested functions?

Comment: i understand you try to debug it. But, why not writting some unit tests?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to debug at the end of the iteration process with map(). That's why I need the error messages. What are unit tests?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the same response to any of the 9 function calls, then you can wrap the whole body of `superFoo` in one `tryCatch`, e.g.

```
superFoo = function (a){
  tryCatch({
    varA = foo(a)

    # IF foo(a) fails, superFoo has to: stop and     return NA

    varB = foo(varA+3)
    varA + varB
  }, error = return(NULL), warning = return(NULL))
}
```

This skips the separate check for `is.null(varA)`.  If you want that, add a line like

```
if (is.null(varA)) stop("varA is NULL")
```

and that will be caught the same as other errors are caught.

Comment: Not every `foo()` function output is the same. Some are tibbles, some vectors and some regression results. I need to stop execution of `superFoo()`, however, at the first foo() function that fails because `foo()` has side-effects (write a graph to a folder or save an Excel file). 
Nevertheless, let assume I can change every `foo()` to output `NULL` when an error, will this `superFoo() tryCatch({},error,warning)` stop execution at the very first `foo()` that fails?

Comment: The code in `tryCatch` will stop at the first error that is signalled.  The `foo()` functions can signal errors by calling `stop()`, or by returning a bad result that you test for.